# Twitter OAuth::Unauthorized 400 Bad Request, doing RailsApps Oauth tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-oauth, railsapps

I'm working on the RailsApps Oauth tutorial, and cannot figure out how to not get a Twitter OAuth::Unauthorized 400 Bad Request when visiting /auth/twitter.

Everything was exactly as https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-omniauth.

Have spent hours googling, multiple variations of callback url, placing different environment variables.

```
    self.token_request(http_method, uri.path, token, request_options, arguments)
  when (400..499)
    raise OAuth::Unauthorized, response
  else
    response.error!
  end
```

Help is much appreciated, just wanna keep learning.

From the terminal:

```
Started GET "/" for 24.255.242.177 at 2015-11-27 17:26:03 +0000
Cannot render console from 24.255.242.177! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  Rendered visitors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (6.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (9.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (6.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 627ms (Views: 625.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/signin" for 24.255.242.177 at 2015-11-27 17:26:06 +0000
Cannot render console from 24.255.242.177! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to https://omniauth-kiefer.c9users.io/auth/twitter
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/auth/twitter" for 24.255.242.177 at 2015-11-27 17:26:06 +0000
Cannot render console from 24.255.242.177! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
I, [2015-11-27T17:26:06.735868 #43672]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Request phase initiated.

OAuth::Unauthorized (400 Bad Request):
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
  omniauth-oauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:28:in `request_phase'
  omniauth-twitter (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:61:in `request_phase'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:215:in `request_call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:183:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails-omniauth/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails-omniauth/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails-omniauth/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails-omniauth/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (99.1ms)
```

Comment: Have you reviewed issues on the OmniAuth repo? Maybe you can open an issue there. https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues

Answer (score -1):

Your auth keys are most likely are setup wrong, just remove the ENV and brackets, like below, try changing...

from:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET'],
end
```

to:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'TWITTER_KEY', 'TWITTER_SECRET'
end
```

Comment: Your callback url shoud be: